# is there any way to clean all projects in gradle 6.0.1

Tags: gradle

I want to clean all project of gradle,now I using this task in root project build.gradle:

```
task clean {
    subprojects.each {
        it.afterEvaluate {
            def cleanTask = it.tasks.findByName('clean')
            if (cleanTask) {
                dependsOn(cleanTask)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it give me tips this clean task already exists,is there other way to do this task?I do not want to write many code like :

```
./gradlew clean projectA
./gradlew clean projectB
./gradlew clean projectC
```

Now I have more than 30 project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a feature in Gradle where:

- If you call a task on the root project
- And the root project does not contain that task
- A "proxy" task will be created in the root project
- The "proxy" task will invoke any tasks with the same name in its subprojects

So usually, your subprojects will contain a "clean" task and your root project will not. So invoking "clean" on the root project will actually invoke "clean" on all the subprojects. I think this is the behavior you want?

If this is not occurring, it's likely you've created a "clean" task in your root project with different behavior (perhaps you applied the "base" plugin to the root project?). I suggest you remove the "clean" task from the root project

Comment: It's not execute the clean task in subproject,I have tried right now.@lance-java

Comment: What plugins have you applied to the root project? With my Gradle projects, the root project will not have any plugins applied. It's just a place for common logic to configure subprojects. I'm guessing you've applied a plugin to the root project which has added a "clean" task

Comment: @Dolphin before trying lance-java's answer, make sure to rename your _clean_ task in your root project to something else like _cleanAll_ (or remove it for testing purposes)